# Volume of the solid formed by the region between y=2 and y=$\sqrt{x-2}$ around y=-2 using the washer method.

Tags: calculus

[image: Graph of the problem.]

To attempt to solve this, I used the radius of the right cylinder created by the line from the interval 0 to 6 and subtracted the volume created by y = $\sqrt{x-2}$. The radius of the right cylinder is πr^2h with radius 2+2=4 and height 6. The volume given by the other function should be:

π $\int_2^6 (\sqrt{x-2}+2)^2 dx $= $136π\over3$

Then my volume = 96π - $136π\over3$ = 159.174, but the answer is 134.04. Where did I make a mistake? Thanks.

Comment: The height of the cylinder is  $h=4$.

Comment: Shouldn't the height of the right cylinder from 0 to 6 be 6 and the radius 4? I can't see why the height would be 4.

Comment: Since the function $y=\sqrt{x-2}$ does not exists for $x<2$, the '' region between $y=2$ and $y=\sqrt{x-2}$ '' starts at $x=2$.

Comment: Since the graphs of $y=2$ and $y=\sqrt{x-2}$ do not bound a region, the problem is ambiguous. @EmilioNovati gives a reasonable interpretation, but the problem is still poorly stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your derivation seems to be correct if the volume is referred to the interval $x\in[0,6]$.